# Convert rows to columns and enter 0 and 1 for matches in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a pandas data frame like this:

[image: Original data set]

and I need to convert it into the below:

[image: Output data set]

So, the unique values in column 'camps' part of the original data set, gets turned into columns with values 0 and 1 for each id. How can I achieve this using Pandas or anything else in Python? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Below is the code to create the original data set:

```
import pandas as pd
cust = {'id': [212175, 286170, 361739, 297438, 415712, 415777, 261700, 314624, 170365, 333254],
        'camps': [':_Camp1_CC SC_Statemt_CCSTMT', ':_Camp1_CC SC_Statemt_CCSTMT', ':_Camp1_Free_DS0742203H_BD03', 
                       ':_Camp1_Over_EO3982112A_BD07', ':_Camp1_Over_EO4022202A_BD16', ':_Camp1_Over_EO4022202A_BD16', 
                      ':_Camp1_AS07_DS0722204H_DD02', ':_Camp1_AS07_DS0722204H_DD02', ':_Camp1_AS07_DS0722204H_DD02', 
                      ':_Camp1_AS07_DS0722204H_DD02']}

cust_df = pd.DataFrame(cust)
```

Comment: did you check pandas `get_dummies` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: or `pd.crosstab(df['id'], df[camps'])`

Comment: Just reading the documentation now. Many thanks @Epsi95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, based on [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(cust_df.id, cust_df.camps)
```

Output:

```
camps   :_Camp1_AS07_DS0722204H_DD02  ...  :_Camp1_Over_EO4022202A_BD16
id                                    ...                              
170365                             1  ...                             0
212175                             0  ...                             0
261700                             1  ...                             0
286170                             0  ...                             0
297438                             0  ...                             0
314624                             1  ...                             0
333254                             1  ...                             0
361739                             0  ...                             0
415712                             0  ...                             1
415777                             0  ...                             1
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pd.get_dummies()
```

for your reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-dummy-variables-in-python-with-pandas/